# MongoDB Map/Reduce very poor perfomance

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am executing MAP/Reduce in Mongo DB and it is extremely unexpectedly slow. I am using very wide document with  700 documents and reduce function performs simple sum and multiplication of each value in document by another value

Performance is very poor,  20 min for only 20K docs,  and linearly growing with number of docs.  Looking into mongotop 99% of the time process i busy writing into temp collection. Any idea on what it is doing and any ways to optimize, anything is missing?

I have used all proper practices, sorted by all emited keys(key1,key2,key3)
Created compound index `db.ensueIndex({Key1:1,Key2:1,Key3:1})`

```
map = function(){

  Key = {
           key1:this.Key1,
           key2:this.Key2,
           key3:this.Key3
        };

   values = this;

  emit(key,values)

}

reduce = function(key,values)
{
    //initialize all values to 0
    var ret = { 
                val1:0,
                val2:0,
                .
                .
                val700:0,
              } 

   values.forEach(function(v){

              val1+=v.val1*v.quantity;
              val2+=v.val2*v.quantity;
              .
              .
              val700+=v.val700*v.quantity;             

    });

    return ret;
}

db.runCommand({mapReduce:coll,map:map,reduce:reduce,out:coucoll,sort:{ke1,key2,key3})
```

Comment: What's a very "wide" document? MapReduce uses a temporary collection to store intermediate results (and final results depending on config). Are you emitting the entire document? That's certainly not going to speed things up.

Comment: By "wide" document I mean , document with 700 keys.  And  yes based on observation of running mongotop it spends most (99%) of the time writing to temp collection.   Yes, I am emiting entire document as most keys/values(95%) are used in reduce caclulation.  What are the other alternatives ?

Comment: So, basically, you're copying the entire collection into a new temporary collection, then possibly a second collection with the results. That's a **LOT** of disk IO. If it's simple math, could it just be performed ad-hoc on the client when reading the data from the source collection?

Comment: That was an idea to try to do aggregation and calculations in mongo rather than doing on a client as it will take time on the cleint as well by itereting over 250K docs and multiplying 700 values in each doc. I hoped Mongo can do it all in reasonable amount of time.  And doing it one place will be easier to maintain by juts modifying reduce function rather implementing it in the client code

Comment: Seems like you have better understanding on how Mongo preforms map/reduce, perhaps you can answer a question that puzzles me. I am running on the large box with 6 core and 96GB and working set (collection) is only 4 GB so theoretically all operations can me performed in memory or at least persisted to disk in batches.  Per timing I get (> 100 min) for 200K dock, I assume it persist one document multiple times one at a time, otherwise I can not explain why it  so slow.  Can Mongo,  or more practical question, can I tune mongo to do save in batches or optimize it somehow

Comment: from the MongoDB console, do: `db.stats()` ..., and add it to your question. I'm a bit surprised with that hardware that it's only writing about 16 docs per second.